# 1120: Access of undefined property error when trying to use setTimeout for a function

Tags: actionscript-3

This is the code

```
package{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

public class background_ extends MovieClip{


    public function background_() {
        // constructor code
    }

    setTimeout(delayed, 3500);

    public function delayed(){
        trace("This function executed 3 and a half seconds after it was called by using the delayedFuctionCall function.");
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows: ...\background_.as, Line 13   1120: Access of undefined property delayed. Line 13 is setTimeout(delayed, 3500); . This class is attached to a background symbol. I intend to make it so that the frame switches after 3 seconds of sitting on the first frame.

Comment: You can't write executable code outside of functions in normal AS3. Put the `setTimeout` function in the constructor `background_()`.

Answer (score 0):

What DodgerThud said is correct, i moved the setTimeout function in the constructor and it worked.